# Sorting of eigensystem accroding to specific eigenvector

Tags: matrix, sorting, eigenvalues

I have a matrix, I want to sort it with respect to specific eigenvectors.

Here, I provided an example of a matrix **HT**:

`HT = {{2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 5}};`

```
{eigs, vecs} = Eigensystem[HT];
list1 = Partition[Riffle[eigs , Abs[Chop[vecs]]], 2]
```

`list1`  will provide the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors.

The output for `list1`  will be following:

```
{{5, {0, 0, 0, 1}}, {4, {0, 0, 1, 0}}, {3, {0, 1, 0, 0}}, {2, {1, 0, 
   0, 0}}}
```

Now, I want to sort with respect to eigenvectors, such that the eigenvactors and their cooresponding eigenvalues in basis of `{0, 0, 1, 0}` comes first, second `{0, 1, 0, 0}` respectively, as following:

```
{{4, {0, 0, 1, 0}},  {3, {0, 1, 0, 0}}, {5, {0, 0, 0, 1}},  {2, {1, 0, 
   0, 0}}}
```

Reason was such sorting is that, I have many matrices of 64x64 dimensions and I am only interested in the eigenvalues of eigenvectors `{0, 0, 1, 0} and {0, 1, 0, 0}`.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can clearly state in your post what exactly ordering do you want to achieve.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you for your quick response, actually the solution you suggested changes the eigenvalues. My desired ordering will be according to the eigenvectors, `{0, 0, 1, 0}`.

Comment: I defined a system as above `HT`, after solving eigensystem,  each eigenvalue will have coressponding eigenvector, described above in list1 and 2. For example, eigenvalue 3 has eigenvector  `{0, 0, 0, 1}` . 
I want my final output to be sorted based on eigenvector `DesiredOUT=`.

Comment: I still do not understand, how your `list1` and `list2` are going to find out what is your `DesiredOUT`. I do not seen any `DesiredOUT` in your program!

Comment: Sorry for my english, as I am not a native english speaker. First, `DesiredOUT` means, this is the output (ordering/sorting of eigenvector) I want.

Comment: Aman, I think what we don’t understand is on what basis your eigenvectors are sorted. For instance, why / according to what sorting rule does {0, 0, 1, 0} come before {0, 1, 0, 0} in your ordering? Clearly you are not using the value of the corresponding eigenvalue to sort, so what exactly are you using?

Comment: Hi @MarcoB, First thank you and sorry for inconvience, I have modified the Question. Actually, I have huge matrix of 64x64 dimension, here I provided a smipler example.
I am only interested in the eigen-vlaues of eigen-vectors {0, 0, 1, 0}  and {0, 1, 0, 0}. So, I want these two values to be  first and second respectively.
In my previous ordering, I was able to sort according to minimum value of eigen-value.

Comment: @Aman If you are really only interested in the eigenvalues corresponding to those two eigenvectors, then you could perhaps filter them out, rather than trying to sort. For instance, with your definition of `HT`, the following will return only those eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs that have the eigenvectors of interest to you: `Cases[Transpose@Eigensystem[HT], {_, {0, 0, 1, 0} | {0, 1, 0, 0}}]`. Would that work?

Comment: @MarcoB, Actually thats really helpful and promising, but what If the values for vectors are such:  `{0, 0, 0.8, 0}`  and ` {0, 0.7, 0, 0}` and in each matrix the weight for eigen-basis changes. As, I have many matrices to digonalize.

Comment: @Aman OK explain in words how you would select the eigenvectors you want. I don't mean in Mathematica, just explain to us how you know which ones are interesting, and how you would do it by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it doesn't seem you really need them sorted. You only need to find the eigenvalues for the eigenvectors of interest. If so, here's a way:

```
evNF = Nearest[Normalize /@ N@Join[vecs, -vecs] -> Join[eigs, eigs]];
vecToVal[ev_?VectorQ] := evNF[Normalize@N@ev];
vecToVal[evs_?MatrixQ] := evNF[Normalize /@ N@evs];

v1 = {0, 0, 1, 0};
v2 = {0, 1, 0, 0};
vecToVal[{v1, v2}]

(*  {{4}, {3}}  *)
```

If you really want them "sorted", here's a way, assuming the eigenvectors `v1` and `v2` are chosen from the ones returned by `Eigensystem`:

```
{v1, v2}~Join~Complement[vecs, {v1, v2}]

(*  {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}  *)
```

If the eigenvector are not known to be among the ones returned by `Eigensystem`, then you can map yours to the computed ones like this:

```
vecNF = Nearest[Normalize /@ N@Join[vecs, -vecs] -> Join[vecs, vecs]];

v1 = {0, 0, 3, 0};
v2 = {0, 7, 0, 0};
v1 = First@vecNF[Normalize@v1];
v2 = First@vecNF[Normalize@v2];
{v1, v2}~Join~Complement[vecs, {v1, v2}]

(*  {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, This is what I am looking for. Also thank you to @MarcoB  and yarchik for help.